# Answer to my own question requires at least two days to be accepted

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Why does accepting my own answer require at least two days before it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are some special rules around owner-accepted answers, to prevent gaming:
>
> 1. **Wait 48 hours.** You must wait 2 days from the time you originally asked your question before you can accept your own answer. This gives other users a chance to answer the question in good faith, and earn the accepted answer.
> 2. **No change in sort order.** Normally, accepted answers are “docked” under the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers; they stay in standard sort order like any other answer.
> 3. **No reputation is earned.** Normally, accepted answers confer +15 rep to the answerer and +2 to the owner. Owner accepted answers do not earn rep (or badges) for anyone.

For more info check [this Meta Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer)